# How to element fixed syncronize with browser scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have element ruler and page in `body`. but when i'm `zoom` scale and `scroll` horizontal, ruler not scroll to `left` or `right`.

how to ruler position same with element page?

```js
$(".ruler").css("zoom", 2);
$("page").css("zoom", 2);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
  padding-top: 1cm;
}

page {
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29cm;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 2.54cm;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ruler {
  position: fixed;
  height: 30px;
  background: #0077CC;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.rulers {
  width: 21cm;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.rulers-line {
  width: 0.5mm;
  height: 0.5cm;
  margin-right: 0.9cm;
  background: #000;
  ;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ruler">
  <div class="rulers">
    <div class="rulers-line"></div>
    <div class="rulers-line"></div>
    <div class="rulers-line"></div>
    <div class="rulers-line"></div>
    <div class="rulers-line"></div>
    <div class="rulers-line"></div>
    <div class="rulers-line"></div>
    <div class="rulers-line"></div>
    <div class="rulers-line"></div>
    <div class="rulers-line"></div>
    <div class="rulers-line"></div>
    <div class="rulers-line"></div>
    <div class="rulers-line"></div>
    <div class="rulers-line"></div>
    <div class="rulers-line"></div>
    <div class="rulers-line"></div>
    <div class="rulers-line"></div>
    <div class="rulers-line"></div>
    <div class="rulers-line"></div>
    <div class="rulers-line"></div>
    <div class="rulers-line"></div>
    <div class="rulers-line"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<page></page>
```

Comment: Not an expert in css by any means, but perhaps this might have something to do with the `position: fixed` in the `.ruler` style?